# Creating Attribute alias

Tags: python, properties, alias, attr

Normally when I have method with long name I create alias:

```
  class .....:

     def very_long_name(self,....):
         ........

     short = very_long_name
```

I want to do the same for attributes

```
     self.very_long_name = ...
     self.short = self.very_long_name
```

I assume **short** is a reference i.e. it does not take memory for a copy.
And second the access speed to the attribute is the same.

Is this correct ?

PS> using @property will be slower,right ?

Comment: There are no attribute references. What you did with the function name is not a reference to the attribute, it's just two names that have the same function value. Redefining one will not affect the other.

Comment: A property is the only solution. Yes, it will be a little slower.